# Android - Second of two surface views leaves black hole in first view

Tags: android, surfaceview, z-order

I have two surface views (MediaPlayer and a separate Video renderer). The MediaPlayer is the first view, the video renderer is the second one.

The first view is using the default Z order. The second one uses `SurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` to be displayed on top of the other surface view. This is working fine except one issue: when I try to close the second surface view, it leaves a black hole at the position it was located before closing it.

It seems to me, that the on-top-surface still locks these pixels so that the first view can't draw on it.

When I re-create the first surface view, the black hole is gone. But, this way I have to re-initialize the whole view.

How do I fix that issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "closing" the second view (i.e. what is your code doing)?  Sounds like the surface is still there and being composited.  There is no "pixel locking"; either the surface is there and being rendered, or it isn't.  `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` will dump the list (along with a ton of other stuff).  See also https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Comment: You're right. I supposed the view being destroyed when I 'close' the fragment with the view. However, the fragment is only being hidden with `FragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide()`, so the view might be still there. What's the safest way to release the surface view without removing the fragment?

Comment: @fadden could you please make an answer out of your comment as this was the solution for my issue. I had to remove the view from the parent container and set the view to `null`.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like you've answered your own question... if you have the time, please write up what you've found in an answer, and (when the system allows) accept it.  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)